# Getting the calculated CSS attributes (ex: width) after view is rendered using Marionette Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I've created a fixed header/footer table based on a pure javascript program logic.

Basically, after loading the page, what I do is to split the original table in 3 other tables, each one containing part of it, as follows: thead, tbody and tfoot.

**As reference, working code can be found bellow:**
(sorry for the long code statement, but I though, as it is working fine, same could be useful for someone else)

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var mainTable = $('.table-scroll');

  // outer contrainer
  var tableOuterContainer = $('<div id="table-outer-container"></div>');
  $(mainTable).after(tableOuterContainer);

  // table header
  var theadCopy = detachTableHeader();
  $(tableOuterContainer).append(theadCopy);

  //table body
  var tableContainer = $('<div id="table-inner-container"></div>');
  $(tableContainer).css('height', '300px');
  $(tableContainer).css('overflow-y', 'auto');
  $(tableContainer).append(mainTable);
  $(tableOuterContainer).append(tableContainer);

  var tfootCopy = detachTableFooter();
  $(tableOuterContainer).append(tfootCopy);

  function detachTableHeader() {
    var clone = $(mainTable).clone();
    $(clone).find('tbody').remove();
    $(clone).find('tfoot').remove();
    $(mainTable).find('thead').remove();
    return clone;
  }

  function detachTableFooter() {
    var clone = $(mainTable).clone();
    $(clone).find('thead').remove();
    $(clone).find('tbody').remove();
    $(mainTable).find('tfoot').remove();
    return clone;
  }

  function adjustTableHeaderWidth() {
    var tbodyColumns = $(mainTable).find('tbody tr:first').children();
    var theadColumns = $(theadCopy).find('thead tr').children();

    var width;
    $(theadColumns).each(function(i, v) {
      width = Math.round($(tbodyColumns[i]).width());
      if (i + 1 < $(theadColumns).length) {
        $(v).width(width);
        $(tbodyColumns[i]).width(width);
      }
    });

    $(theadCopy).css('margin-bottom', '0');
    $(theadCopy).css('border-bottom', '0');
  }

  function adjustTableFooterWidth() {
    var tbodyColumns = $(mainTable).find('tbody tr:first').children();
    var tfootColumns = $(tfootCopy).find('tfoot tr').children();

    var width;
    $(tfootColumns).each(function(i, v) {
      width = Math.round($(tbodyColumns[i]).width());
      if (i + 1 < $(tfootColumns).length) {
        $(v).width(width);
        $(tbodyColumns[i]).width(width);
      }
    });

    $(mainTable).css('margin-bottom', '0');
    $(mainTable).css('border-bottom', '0');
    $(tfootCopy).css('border-top', '0');
  }

  // Adjust the width of thead cells when window resizes
  $(window).resize(function() {
    adjustTableHeaderWidth();
    adjustTableFooterWidth();
  }).resize(); // Trigger resize handler
}); //]]>
```

Problem is now, I'd like to migrate the code above for using it in a Marionette Backbone view, but can't do it, because I need widths to be got, in order to align the columns in the new tables created, but when I try doing it values are zero (0) in the render (onRender) function.

So, my question is: **Is there any way for me to get the calculated CSS values, using Backbone, similar to what I have done above?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding a script tag inside the $el, forcing it to be executed after the view has been displayed, so the CSS is calculated already:

```
onShow : function () {
    this.$el.append('<script>require(["table_fixedheader"], function () {jq.detachTableHeaderAndFooter();});');
}
```

Note script tag has not been closed. Did it intentionally as the framework is going to take care of closing it. Otherwise, it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone Views are just wrappers around jQuery elements. You can use the `$el` property which holds a cached reference to the jQuery element associated with the view to modify the width. Here's an example where the width is changed on resize.

```
var TableView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: "#my-table",

    render: function() {
        this.$el.css("width", "80%");
        return this;
    },

    resize: function() {
        //perform the resize here.
    }
});

var table = new TableView().render();

$(window).resize(function() {
    table.resize();
}
```

**Important:** The code assumes that a `#my-table` element already exists in the DOM. If you're creating a new element using Backbone,  ensure that the table is rendered on the DOM before changing its size.

Comment: I probably got no success trying to explain myself. Summarizing it, my problem is actually getting CSS attributes (ex: width), not setting it, before page rendering, in the Backbone view. Just occurred something that would probably work. I'm going to add the script above inside the page template, instead of try getting the CSS inside the view, ensuring script would be executed just after the table is displayed (and css attributes calculated), allowing me to get the CSS values I need. I will post it here, in case I succeed doing it. Anyway, many thanks for your comments.